# WPF: Why does CommandBindings only use RoutedCommand which breaks MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I apologize for this somewhat general question, but I don't understand the logic behind CommandBindings in WPF.

They only allow for RoutedCommands, which I generally don't want to use because I need my logic to be in the ViewModel (I want to adhere to MVVM as much as I can). Why not allow for ICommands? Why only RoutedCommands?

I want to reap the benefits of a single object with command logic + key bindings, so that I can use a command from a context menu, a key shortcut and possibly a button too, and have everything done automatically for me. Since I don't want to use RoutedCommands, It seems that I'll have to inherit from MenuItem and ICommand and implement my own version of a Window's CommandBindings. That's not too difficult, but is that the right thing to do? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide pseudo code example of how do you want it to work? Because menu item has Command property of type `ICommand`, button too, so you can just bind them to command in your viewmodel if you like. And command bindings + routed commands is entirely UI concept which has nothing to do with view models.

Comment: According to the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 it's ICommand all the way down. Please [edit] to add examples of what you're claiming is true.

Comment: @Will while true, the same docs say "A CommandBinding has limited use with an ICommand that is not a RoutedCommand", that's probably what OP means. Anyway I agree that examples are necessary here.